# Why does flexbox behave differently on mobile?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigation

I want to create a fixed navigation with a burger icon that when clicked, it opens up a full width and full height overlay flexbox-menu. This is the code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaLMQK

This works well on desktop browsers, but not so much on ios (haven’t had the chance to test it on android yet).

The following **2 problems** arise when viewed on mobile:

1. The fixed navigation is not fixed to the top anymore
2. The flexbox behaves weird. It overflows to the full height of the page, and the separate flexbox-items become as large as the screen.

There is probably a very simple solution to this, but I can’t seem to get my head around it… Help is much appreciated!

CSS:

```
  body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

/*Sticky Navbar*/
/*Nav*/
#header-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: .6s ease .2s;
}
.header-nav-open {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

/*Burger*/
.nav_button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0em 1em;
}

.nav_button #burger {
  position: relative;
}
.nav_button #burger span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.nav_button #burger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}
.nav_button #burger span:nth-child(2), .nav_button #burger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 8px;
}
.nav_button #burger span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 16px;
}

/*Overlay Nav*/
.main-nav {
    background: #000;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .6s ease .2s;
}
.main-nav-open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: opacity .6s ease .2s;
}

.nav-item {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
    -ms-flex: 1 33.3333333%;
    flex: 1 33.3333333%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-item-bg {
    opacity: .5;
    position: absolute;
    background: #323232;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.nav-item:hover .nav-item-bg {
  opacity: .6;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .nav-item {
     flex: 1 50%;
  }
}

.main-nav .nav-item h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.main-nav .nav-item h2 {
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*Content*/
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.main {
  padding: 100px 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.main p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 1.125em;
}
```

Comment: It works fine outside codepen I think it has bugs rendering css position fixed.